# "The type ... is not exported from this module" warning

Tags: java, methods, module, export, warnings

I got a warning I couldn't figure out what the problem is.
Maybe I googled for the wrong words, I don't know.
I hope someone could tell me what the warning actually means.

My programm works fine, but I think there is a reason for this warning and I want to know what it is.

[image]

Edit: I can show the whole code if needed, but it's literally just a class that uses another class in it's methods.
I did the same in other projects before, without such a warning.

Comment: Does your project contain a module-info.java?  What is in it?

Comment: It does. It contains exports for some of my classes, but not all.

`module MusicOverlay {

 exports overlay;

 exports dataProcessing;
 exports persistence;
 exports winkeyboard;

 requires java.desktop;
}`
Edit: Ugh, ugly formation.

Comment: Okay, I see that module descriptor exports four packages.  Is the `Song` class in any of those four packages?

Comment: Song has it's own package that is none of those four.
Should I add it's package to the module-info.java?

Comment: Yes.  Exporting a package is the only way to make the classes of that package visible to other modules.  A public method in an exported package needs to make use of types that are themselves exported.

Comment: Warning is gone. Thanks. :)